# CDN links in index.html giving errors

Tags: html, reactjs, tags

THE ERROR READS: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.html

CDN links that I used:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Please help, I'm trying to deploy a React environment from scratch and I'm stuck at the 1st step.

Comment: try ading this meta tag to your html file `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside head tag

Comment: That's not an error, that's a *warning*. You should add something like `charset="utf-8"` to your `html` tag.

Comment: Yup you're right. its fixed thanks!